# Website Resizing Grid Layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, grid

I have seen these grid style layouts around on the web for quite some time, and would like to know if anyone knew about a framework or resource for me to get started in creating a layout of a similar fashion.

Here is a specific layout that I thought was quite nice, and has a great animation when resizing the page:
http://www.smashbros.com/us/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is a pretty common framework for developing mobile friendly websites.

Answer (score 0):

I think your after a more specific library than Bootstrap. We are all living in grid hell.

Here is a list of popular fluid grids that might get you closer than Bootstrap.

- http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/
- http://masonjs.com/
- http://gridster.net/

A quick google for `jquery fluid grids` may help as well.